# Laravel 5.3 array validation

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm making a Laravel app and have a form that users can add input fields to with javascript. The form therefore has multiple inputs with the same name.

e.g. `<input name='date[]' class='form-control' ...`

In the update action in my controller I can loop through the inputs and update my database without any issues. The problem is when I try to add validation.

I have tried using the validate method provided through Controller ValidatesRequest trait..

```
$this->validate($request, ['date.*' => 'required']);
```

but I receive this error:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 519
>   "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

I then followed approved answer in this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140956/laravel-5-2-array-validation)

so in my controller I manually created a validator like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['date.*' => 'required']);
```

when I `dd($validator->messages());` I can see that the validations are being hit and the messages are generating correctly but when I go to send those error messages to my view like this:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
                     ->withErrors($validator)
                     ->withInput();
}
```

I get the same error as before:

ErrorException in helpers.php line 519 htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I have read Laravel docs on validating arrays (a short section), and have tried googling my problem w/o success. Any help would be much appreciated.